# Get row when a value first exceeds a threshold and then remains above it

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID Date        Value
1  2010-08-01  6
1  2011-05-01  8
1  2011-12-01  7
1  2012-08-01  6
1  2013-01-01  6
1  2014-04-01  10
1  2014-08-01  8
1  2015-01-01  9
1  2016-01-01  9
1  2017-01-01  8
2  1996-01-01  5
2  1998-01-01  8
2  2010-01-01  5
2  2014-08-01  8
2  2016-01-01  8
```

I want to detect, for each `ID`, the first row that `Value` **is equal to or exceeds** a set threshold (in this case: 8) and **remains** over this threshold for the following observations. So, based on the data frame, the result I would like to obtain would be the following:

```
ID Date       Value 
1 2014-04-01  10
2 2014-08-01  8
```

I truly appreciate your help! Thanks!
Let me know if you need any additional information or clarification

Comment: Suppose if it doesn't remain till the last element for an ID, what would be the output for that ID, should you skip those IDs

Comment: Yes, if it doesn't remain till the last element I would want that ID to be dropped. So, I believe your answer already takes that into account. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear about the `remains` case - i.e. suppose an ID have 'Value' less than 8 for the last element, then it is not clear whether to return row for that ID or not.  The below solution will skip those 'ID' (if exists)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
   slice({ind = Value >= 8
         grp = rleid(ind)
        if(all(ind[grp == max(grp)])) 
      first(row_number()[grp == max(grp)]) else 0
  }) %>% 
ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ID Date       Value
  <int> <chr>      <int>
1     1 2014-04-01    10
2     2 2014-08-01     8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Date = c("2010-08-01", "2011-05-01", "2011-12-01", 
"2012-08-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-08-01", "2015-01-01", 
"2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "1996-01-01", "1998-01-01", "2010-01-01", 
"2014-08-01", "2016-01-01"), Value = c(6L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alt 1. Using `rev` to perform the check of values from the end of each group. Grab the index of the first `FALSE` (`which.min`), i.e. the last value below the threshold in the original order. Convert the "reversed" index to original indexing by subtracting it from group length `.N`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)

d[ , {
  rv = rev(Value >= 8)
  .SD[.N - which.min(rv) + 2]
  }, by = ID] 

#    ID       Date Value
# 1:  1 2014-04-01    10
# 2:  2 2014-08-01     8
```

---

Maybe add a check if values drop below 8 before the end, i.e. check the first element in the reversed vector:

```
d[ , {
  rv = rev(Value >= 8)
  if(!rv[1]) NA else {
    .SD[.N - which.min(rv) + 2]
  }
}, by = ID]
```

---

Alt 2. Using run-length encoding:

```
d[ , if(Value[.N] >= 8){
  g = rleid(Value >= 8)
  .SD[g == max(g)][1]
  }, by = ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `rle` to check the starting point of exceeding the threshold and from which we always have the following values greater than the threshold

```
th <- 8

subset(
  df,
  ave(Value >= th,
    ID,
    FUN = function(v) {
      with(
        rle(v),
        cumsum(lengths)[length(lengths) - 1] + 1 == seq_along(v) & values[length(lengths)]
      )
    }
  )
)
```

gives

```
   ID       Date Value
6   1 2014-04-01    10
14  2 2014-08-01     8
```